# Hide the taskbar using C#

Tags: c#, windows, security, kiosk

I am running Windows XP 64 bit. I want to hide the taskbar when I run my application.

I tried codes by searching the web. In all those, it hides the task bar. But the problem is, when i open a notepad and maximize it, it is not actually into full screen. Because the space where task bar was there is still blocked with empty space. I want it fit really into full screen mode.

Comment: I'm going to retitle this, Make application Full Screen using C#, since what you really want is fullscreen, not programatically hiding parts of the OS from the user (maybe the user wants it there).

Comment: @sixlettervariables, the purpose of hiding the task bar is not allowing the user to use start button in the taskbar. So i need to hide it. This is the Kiosk application, so i disable all the key shortcuts and windows key as well.

Comment: You may want to look at replacing the default shell with your own custom program. That is likely easier than trying to hide/disable Explorer features if your program is to run a kiosk.

Comment: Then his question is not how to hide the taskbar using C#, but rather how to make a Kiosk application in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done this by making the application borderless, maximized, and setting it to be Topmost.  Here's a [perfect example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FullScreenDotNetApp.aspx) from CodeProject.

As one of the commenters has said, <del>replacing</del> disabling Explorer and running your application might be the best way, security-wise.

Comment: Of course, you can't replace Explorer using C#... but I agree that it's the best option, provided that it's an option.

Comment: I know I can kill the Explorer.exe process from within the Task Manager - explorer windows and taskbar disappear.  I don't know if it's possible or wise to kill it programmatically, though.

Answer (score 6):

If you like to replace the windows shell (taskbar) you'll have to change a registry key.

Changing the default shell (all users):

1. open regedit (start menu > run, and type in regedit)
2. go to: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon.
3. Change Shell from explorer.exe to your program path and name e.g. c:\myKioskApp\Kiosk.exe

Changing the default shell (only current user):

1. open regedit (start menu > run, and type in regedit).
2. go to: HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon.
3. add a new string value (Edit > New > String Value) called shell. and set the value to the path of the new shell e.g. c:\myKioskApp\Kiosk.exe
4. log out and log back in.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Hide your task bar  by setting Following Properties of your C# Form.

WindowState     : Maximized
FormBorderStyle : FixedDialog

Answer (score 0):

on window 7 (or maybe higher) using `FormWindowState.Maximized` is wrong because the maximum size will be subtracted by Taskbar height but you can do this

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; // or default
this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
this.TopMost = true;

// do it here
this.Location = new Point(0,0);
var fullscreenSize = new Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
this.Size = fullscreenSize;
```