# How To Disable Desktop and/or Taskbar

Tags: winforms, desktop, taskbar

I know the implications of this but a client was insistent that they wanted a program we've made to lock the desktop and/or taskbar so as to prevent the user from switching programs.  I'd already explained the implications of this but they were still insistent that the desktop be locked down. How is this behavior possible? I'm using .NET Winforms btw but any other approach is welcome.

If possible, I'm looking for something similar to how Internet Cafe managers can lock the screen and prevent all access to other applications.  If there's a simpler solution to prevent access to other programs aside from this one I'm open to suggestions as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a [Full Screen dot net app](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FullScreenDotNetApp.aspx) tutorial using the "kiosk" lead (didn't know it was the term for it) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344652/hide-the-taskbar-using-c)

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to that code anymore (it was at previous job) and I don't just remember how I did it, but I do remember that the last time I had to do it, the key to figuring how from searching the web is the word 'kiosk'.

Comment: ohh.. Thanks for the lead. I'll check it out now.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a registry setting for the Windows Shell program, and you want to change it from launching the standard shell to launching your own program instead. I don't remember the details.