# C# Hide Clock And TaskBar

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hide the taskbar using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344652/hide-the-taskbar-using-c)

hello I'm writing a program that allows me to control windows, my question is how can you hide
clock and taskbar??
Thx

Comment: You could try downloading the .NET virus toolkit.

Comment: ever tried using google? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e231f5be-5233-4eee-b142-7aef50f37287

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Hide the taskbar using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344652/hide-the-taskbar-using-c)

Its almost the same question. You can download the sample project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FullScreenDotNetApp.aspx)