# Running just an app on windows 7

Tags: c#

I have to run my C# application that I wrote it recently on several computers with window 7 operating system. Here is a big challenge with it, Application must run on startup and user must not be able to work with anything else such as windows hotkeys, other applications, some directories and etc. 
Considering I don’t want to kill any process or service as less as possible, Please give me the best solution.
Thanks and waiting

---

Maybe A little more information will help
did you see Devices like ATMs or Medical devices that window is running on? Those devices don't allow user to manipulate with desktop or anywhere else, I want their solution. . . my Application Will run as a device handler(A Medical Device in Operating room).

Comment: you need to hook into windows dll. may be pinvoke..

Comment: "kiosk mode" is the phrase you are looking for. That should help improve your search results.

Comment: @gideon I won't be installing on my machine :)

Comment: @AmarPalsapure :) mrArmg you need to better explain the purpose of your program, or your question will get closed shortly.

Comment: thanks so guys but It's not really scary, It is my University Challenge :D

Comment: People should calm down.  There are actually quite legitimate purposes for this type of installation.

Comment: @gideon I want windows just for running my app with restricting user to do anything else.

Comment: @Rich.Carpenter yea just realized coming across a program like this for a cyber cafe, which would only let you use the PC per hour if you paid, mrArmg is not very clear on why he wants such functionality though.

Comment: @gideon did you see Devices like ATMs or Medical devices that window is running on? Those devices don't allow user to manipulate with desktop or anywhere else, I want their solution. . . my Application Will run as a device handler(A Medical Device in Operating room).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably shouldn't write such an application in the first place (nagware?).

Anyway. I think what you are looking for is actually ["kiosk" software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kiosk_software). Here is [blog entry](http://jaredheinrichs.com/how-to-turn-a-windows-7-pc-into-a-kiosk.html) that describes how to lock down the computer to effectively run in "kiosk mode".

Note however, that not every application can (or should) be used in that mode. Either because it has loopholes that still allow you to do thing (for example the file open/save dialog still allows you to create directories or navigate the file system), or because they were simply not designed with that goal in mind.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Christian, anyway I have a new way now.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds actually like a (very) bad idea to me...

You could probably hook every Keyboard event so you disable OS shortcut (Windows + D, Windows + E...). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3540572/global-hook-keylogger-problem.).

Also [hide the Windows taskbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1344652/hide-the-taskbar-using-c-sharp).

Make sure your application [starts with Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089601/run-the-application-at-windows-startup).

This sounds a bit hacky to me...

Comment: Dear ken2k thanks for your reply, Be sure about my goal, there isn't any reason for my answer except solving my challenge.

Answer (score 0):

A program with the properties you mention is called a (very restrictive flavour of) shell. So you need to register your program as a shell (instead of explorer.exe) for the poor, poor user you want to restrict.

Answer (score 0):

You might look into using a local group policy to enforce this restriction. [Check this out](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/).